# Woocommerce Bulk discount

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to apply discount on specific item??
I want to apply discount on my pizza site like, If customer order one small & one large pizza then discount may not apply. 
my disounts settings applying to all items. when customer order one small and one large pizza, discount may apply.
I want to apply discount policy on same items, like, if customer order two small or two large pizzas.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an extra plugin as I don't think it includes it in the standard woo commerce. This is how I done it for a project.

Here's link for plugin
https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-bulk-discount/

You can find more extensions to woo commerce if you need them by clicking on woo commerce in the admin panel and then selecting add-ons, there's a fair few to choose from